# Cannot disable kernel updates on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kernel, updates, update-manager, pinning

I have `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS`. Update manager will try to update the kernel version, unfortunately this causes issues with certain applications/drivers I use. Each time I have to manually deselect the kernel packages that it lists for update.

I tried the following

```
smalek@sephr-XPS13-9333:~$ sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic linux-image-generic-lts-quantal 
linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic was already set on hold.
```

I open up update manager and still get kernel updates listed.

I don't want to update kernel and need these permanently ignored by update manager. Anyone have a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Go to Synaptic Package Manager

2 - Enter [package name] into the search field

3 - Highlight the installed package

4 - Click on Package on the top row

5 - Select Lock Version

Done, now [package name] will no longer be updated.